# SQL Server: Select data from tab delimited file with OPENROWSET and BULK returns empty result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openrowset

I want to query data from a tab delimited file using SQL Server and `OPENROWSET`.

I have the following sample source file:

```
FirstName   LastName    EMail
Marny   Haney   sed.dictum.eleifend@sem.com
Alexa   Carpenter   Vivamus.non.lorem@consectetuereuismod.com
Wyatt   Mosley  est@tortoratrisus.org
Cedric  Johns   lectus.a.sollicitudin@quisurna.ca
Lavinia Fischer nibh@insodales.net
Vera    Marshall    scelerisque@sapienAeneanmassa.co.uk
Beau    Frost   vel.quam.dignissim@mauris.net
Halla   Fisher  amet.metus.Aliquam@ullamcorpervelit.co.uk
Sierra  Randall Nulla@magnis.net
Noel    Malone  semper@porttitor.org
```

I'm using the following format file:

```
12.0
3
1     SQLCHAR        0     5           ""      1     FirstName                                                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2     SQLCHAR        0     5           ""      2     LastName                                                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3     SQLCHAR        0     27          "0x0A"  3     EMail                                                       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I'm trying to query the data from the file with the following statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'C:\data\Source\sample_data.dwo'
        ,FORMATFILE= 'C:\data\Format\sample_data.FMT'
        ,FIRSTROW = 2
        ) AS a
```

Unfortunately, the query returns an empty result. I don't get an error.

As far as I understood the default Terminator for fields is `\t`. I also tried to use `t` and `\t` explicitly as a terminator but still no result.

Any suggestions what I can try next?

Link to both files:
https://github.com/LordTakeshiXVII/files/blob/master/sample_data.FMT
https://github.com/LordTakeshiXVII/files/blob/master/sample_data.dwo

Comment: When you say it's blank, do you at least get the correct column headers and data types?

Comment: Yes, i do get the correct column headers in my result pane, but without any data. From the top of my head i don't know how to check the data types. I'm using SSMS for executing the Select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt your format file:

- First change the max-length of the fields to something appropriate (100 in the example) - you can also set it to zero for unlimited input length.
- Second set the terminator for the first two fields to `\t` and of the third field to `\r\n`

```
12.0
3
1  SQLCHAR  0  100  "\t"    1  FirstName  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2  SQLCHAR  0  100  "\t"    2  LastName   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3  SQLCHAR  0  100  "\r\n"  3  EMail      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Here you can find more information on format files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017